# How to use NSFetchedResultsController to return total of a relationship property given a predicate

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm writing an expense tracker app and this is my data model:

[image]

In one screen where I show a periodic (e.g. daily) summary of expenses, I want to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch all the categories and the totals of their expenses *for every single period* (e.g. every day). A period is defined by two `NSDate` variables--a `startDate` and an `endDate`, because I will have weekly and monthly views, too--which I think should be dependent on the index of the summary in the `NSFetchedResultsController`. I also want the `NSFetchedResultsController` to return the category even if the sum is zero. I don't know how to set this up.

What I've tried: I've successfully built an `NSFetchedResultsController` on my `Category` entity and used an `NSExpressionDescription` to get the total of its `expenses` relationship, but it totals all expenses and I can't find a way to specify an inclusive period.

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Category.entityName)
request.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
request.propertiesToFetch = [
    "name", "color",
    {
        let totalColumn = NSExpressionDescription()
        totalColumn.name = "total"
        totalColumn.expression = NSExpression(format: "@sum.expenses.amount")
        totalColumn.expressionResultType = .DecimalAttributeType
        return totalColumn
    }()
]
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
let fetcher = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: App.state.mainQueueContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

I've also been reading about fetched properties, but I also can't find a way to indicate the `startDate` and `endDate` in the predicate before the `NSFetchedResultsController` fires the fetch. Help?

Comment: Is there a reason for using `NSFetchedResultsController`?  I don't think it will be able to deliver what you want (at least, not without a lot of work).  It might be possible for a single period (day, week, etc), but you need *every* single period.  You would have to rebuild the predicate and reperform the fetch for each and every period.  It might be easier just to iterate through all the Expenses and calculate the total amount for each combination of Category and period.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a predicate to your fetch request:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", startDate, endDate];
```